# SSRS Report grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I need to create a SSRS report with changes in UI. Previous my report format was like this:

[image: this is original format]

This is new RDL format I created but grouping is creating issue:

[image: after.png]

I created this format in report design but data is not coming the way I want. My data is grouping by prospect and wellname.

Here is new format in excel sheet.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lozF8pdnsWNC-bXqR2gyNyn8O_nGPze1/view?usp=sharing

also here is snapshot of new format:
[image]

and data is coming in this format from SQL server
[image]

Comment: OK, that's a reasonable statement of requirements. What trouble are you having in implementing it? Is it the query you are stuck on? What would readers need to see to help with that trouble?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It looks like I have asked you to refrain from pleading before, so I am downvoting this time. Please remember that you are addressing volunteers, and they will not be hurried based on your deadlines.

Comment: The first screens hot is a report with data and the second is a design view.. can you mock up in excel or something what you want the output to look like?

Comment: In second screenshot that was the new format in which I want data to be like.

Comment: Help me help you.. <Expr> is not what you want in your output.. it's an rdl design layout! Please make an effort to actually show the desired output

Comment: Hi Harry, now I have uploaded the screenshot of new format in excel an as well as in image also data format I am getting from SQL server using stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly straight forward report.
Add a tablix

Add a parent group on the tablix (Prospectname)

The tablix will add a column in the far left.

Right click on this column and delete it.. it will ask you if you want to delete the column as well as the group. Delete only the column, NOT the group.

Now right click on the DETAIL row and click insert row -> OUTSIDE group. Notice the brackets on the left.. anything outside the bracket is not inside the group.

Now place your header information inside the new row and your details inside your details.

You can add another header row... merge the rows and type.. "No data found".. set the hidden properties for this row based on countrows("nameofprospectgroup").

Do the same for a blank line at end of each group.. rightclick and insert a line below the detailed row but inside the group..

You can do the same with your summary row. 
Play around a bit.. you will figure it out. Good luck

Comment: Hey, you told to group by prospectname but I need to group by prospectname and wellname i.e. by two columns which is not working. Also you have told just abt creating one tablix but here I need two. I created second also but its not giving result in format I needed. Could you help little bit more in detail.

Comment: Add a child group for wellname.. when it adds a column.. delete that column (but not the group..just like in the answer).. now you will see 2 brackets on the left.. one is for prospectname group and the other for wellname group.. why do you need the second tablix??

Answer (score 0):

After doing all the things, I tried to make report by following this post

http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2012/03/ssrs-how-to-show-tablix-inside-tablix.html

it helped and worked for me.